# Error when starting Yesod app on openshift - command line args?

Tags: openshift, yesod

I am getting the following error when (re)starting my Yesod app on openshift:

```
server: InvalidYaml (Just (YamlException "Yaml file not found: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"))
```

Where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is an IP address.  I did find a link to a Heroku+Yesod issue saying something about "removing an argument" but it didn't say from where, and of course the scripts/settings are going to be different in the case of OpenShift.  Any ideas what this error is and how to get past it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming based on the question that you're using the standard scaffolding. If you look in the [code](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold/blob/postgres/Application.hs#L132), you'll find that uses [loadAppSettingsArgs](http://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-2.5/yesod-1.4.1.5/Yesod-Default-Config2.html#v:loadAppSettingsArgs), which is described as:

> Same as loadAppSettings, but get the list of runtime config files from the command line arguments.

If you don't want to pay attention to command line arguments, just replace the call to `loadAppSettingsArgs` with `loadAppSettings []`.

Comment: Yep, I found that this morning :).  Thanks!